# Jackson ignore serializing field depending on value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know it's possible to ignore fields if they are null or if they are empty, but is it possible to ignore a field, for example if it is a String, and contains a certain substring?

Comment: you can use manual parser for it https://github.com/pushpendrachauhan/manual-json-parser It shows three different json library to manually parse json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible if you e.g. use a combination of `@JsonIgnore` and a `Converter`.

If you assume the following `Person` POJO:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Person {
    private final String email;
    private final String name;

    public Person(final String name, final String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    // Will use special conversion before serializing
    @JsonSerialize(converter = EmailConverter.class)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    // Will simply use default serialization
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In the POJO you define that only non-empty values should be included. Furthermore, it is declared that a specific converter is to be used for the `email` property. The converter can be defined like this:

```
public class EmailConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(final String value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value)
                .filter(email -> email.length() > 0)
                .filter(email -> email.contains("@"))
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Note that the converter uses `Optional` which is a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) feature but any validation code will do just fine. When null is returned it is simply skipped since it was declared that way in the `Person` class.

For more info, check out the JavaDocs for [Converter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/) and [@JsonSerialize](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html).

Comment: I guess that would work. I was hoping I could do it without writing too much extra code for specific cases but maybe there's no other way. Thanks !