# How to ignore field totally by its value when serializing with Jackson with annotation on that field?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Almost the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28878847/6413377) but the accepted answer does not fit the general need. Having Simple class and custom serializer like:

**Example class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ExampleClass {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonSerialize(using = StringSerializer.class)
    private String stringNull;        
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonSerialize(using = StringSerializer.class)
    private String stringOk = "ok";
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonSerialize(converter = StringSerializer.class)
    private String stringNotOk = "notOk";        
}
```

**Custom serializer**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static class StringSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {
    public StringSerializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) 
            throws IOException {
        if(value != null && value.equals("ok")) {
            gen.writeString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

So I only want to print out elements that are equal to "ok" but if not equal to "ok" I do not want to print anything. Works fine except for `stringNotOk`. When calling ObjectMappper like:

```
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new ExampleClass());
```

it produces "bad" JSON:

> {"stringOk":"ok","stringNotOk"}

Is there any other way or can I can avoid to raise the serializer to class level and create it separately for each class having such field na taking account field name etc...?

Can I - for example - somehow "revert" back and remove the name "stringNotOk" from already written JSON?

How could this be made in a generic way so that just one serializer and an annotation on needed fields were used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like

`@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = OkFilter.class)`

```
public class OkFilter {

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     //your logic for finding 'ok' value here
  }
}
```

Here you can read more about this
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-include-customized.html